# SWT dependency artifact missing?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, swt

I want to use swt in my project and used this page as a starting point:
https://code.google.com/p/swt-repo/

I added the repository and dependency but my pom.xml has an error saying: 
Missing artifact org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86:jar:4.4

What could be the problem?

My whole pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>artifact</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>swt-repo</id>
            <url>https://swt-repo.googlecode.com/svn/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no official maven repository that hosts the SWT library files. There were a few sites that worked in the past, but almost all are now abandoned, closed or moved. On https://github.com/maven-eclipse/maven-eclipse.github.io they explain the problem, but the solution described there (to use http://maven-eclipse.github.io/maven) doesn't work because that link will redirect you to the git repository.

The link you posted seems to be the only maven repo that is currently left. I had problems with Maven accessing it properly just like you. I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. I suspect it has something to do with missing or invalid indexes, but I'm not sure. In any case the best solution is to download the required jars and add them to your local repository manually. This is probably a good idea anyway, because Google Code will shutdown in January 2016

BTW, there is [an open bug for SWT to be distributed via Maven](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=199302), but it's been posted in 2007! and there still is no official solution.